# What is the best way to improve speed with the Total Immersion stroke?

Tags: swimming

I've found excellent results with endurance, per se, with the   TI stroke, but as I've seen great gains there, my speed had remained relatively constant.

What is best to focus on to turn on the jets with TI?

Comment: Perhaps this question can help you, http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/7944/3778

Comment: My personal opinion is that TI does not teach a fast stroke. However, that being said, the function of speed in the water is a combination of good technique, and a lot of time going very very fast with long rest breaks (intervals), and somewhat fast on short rest (threshold work).

Answer (score 5):

The synopsis at that link is very good.  The gist is that what you want is to increase thrust-per-stroke.  If you look at Olypmic swimmers or even just fast swimmers at your pool, their arms don't fly around faster than everyone else's, they just get more per stroke than anyone else does.  A good way to developing a powerful stroke is to slow down.  Perform the most powerful stroke you can without over-rotating and without injuring yourself, then hold your form until you come nearly to a complete stop.  Repeat.  Use this exercise to fine tune your "power stroke".  I can get across a 25m pool in about 6 or 7 power strokes and I know people who can do it in 4.  Once your power stroke feels good, speed it up gradually until you find your natural power stroke "gait".  You should try to squeeze most of the forward thrust from each stroke before you start counter-rotating for your next stroke.